# Alternatives to nested foreach when comparing list contents based on some (not all) property values

Tags: c#, foreach, big-o

As part of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34425693/16391), it was pointed out repeatedly that I had an O(n^2) problem using code similar to this...

```
public class Foo
{
  public string IdentityValue {get;set;}  
  public string Prop1 {get;set;}
  public string Prop2 {get;set;}

}

List<Foo> itemSet1 = GenerateLargeItemSet(); //makes a large list, > 5000 items for example
List<Foo> itemSet2 = GenerateLargeItemSet();

foreach (var itemFromSet1 in itemSet1)
{

  //does a corresponding item exist in itemSet2?
  var itemSet2Item = itemSet2.FirstOrDefault(i => i.IdentityValue == itemFromSet1.IdentityValue);

  if (itemSet2Item != null)
  { 
    //do stuff to create item in the persistent store
  }
  else
  {
    //do stuff to update item in the persistent store
  }
}
```

Excusing the string comparison and parallelization considerations, is there a cheap and generic (objects may be type T, and the Identity property may be something else) way to reduce the O(n^2) nature of this?

Comment: You can create a set out of one of the lists. This way you get `O(n)`.

Comment: Can either of you provide an answer explaining what you mean?

Comment: instead of `itemSet2` being a list, make it a real set and the lookup there will be `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`.

Comment: @ndn - Its a list coming into the method that contains the for loop. I can convert it as Vadim suggests below, if thats what you mean.

Comment: Yes, if you convert it the complexity will remain `O(n)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of solutions is to use [Enumerable.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join(v=vs.100).aspx) method which have complextiy [O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799427/what-guarantees-are-there-on-the-run-time-complexity-big-o-of-linq-methods)

```
List<Foo> itemSet1 = GenerateLargeItemSet(); //makes a large list, > 5000 items for example
List<Foo> itemSet2 = GenerateLargeItemSet();

// O(n)
var joinedSet = itemSet1.Join(itemSet2, s1 => s1.IdentityValue, s2 => s2.IdentityValue, (f1, f2) => f1).ToList();

// O(n)
foreach (var joinedItem in joinedSet)
{
    //do stuff to create item in the persistent store
}

// O(n)
var unjoinedSet = itemSet1.Except(joinedSet);

// O(n)
foreach (var unjoinedItem in unjoinedSet)
{
    //do stuff to update item in the persistent store
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A well known way of improving the database queries speed is creating an index. The same principle can be applied here.  But what is an index? It's just a data structure that allows fast searching. In BCL such structure is called `Dictionary`. So you can use something like this which will have O(N) time complexity

If the value is unique inside the set

```
var item2Index = itemSet2.ToDictionary(item => item.IdentityValue);
```

If not

```
var item2Index = itemSet2.GroupBy(e => e.IdentityValue)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First());
```

and then

```
foreach (var itemFromSet1 in itemSet1)
{
    //does a corresponding item exist in itemSet2?
    Foo itemSet2Item;
    if (!item2Index.TryGetValue(itemFromSet1.IdentityValue, out itemSet2Item))
    { 
        //do stuff to create item in the persistent store
    }
    else
    {
        //do stuff to update item in the persistent store
    }
}
```

If you want just to check for a duplicate item in the second set, but don't actually need the duplicate item, then you can use a simple `HashSet` (another BCL data structure for fast lookup)

```
var item2Keys = new HashSet<string>(itemSet2.Select(e => e.IdentityValue));
foreach (var itemFromSet1 in itemSet1)
{
    //does a corresponding item exist in itemSet2?
    if (!item2Keys.Contains(itemFromSet1.IdentityValue))
    { 
        //do stuff to create item in the persistent store
    }
    else
    {
        //do stuff to update item in the persistent store
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` first and then use its fast lookups it provides almost `O(1)` :

```
 List<Foo> itemSet1 = GenerateLargeItemSet(); //makes a large list, > 5000 items for example
Dictionary<string, Foo> itemSet2 = GenerateLargeItemSet().ToDictionary(i => i.IdentityValue);

//O(N)
foreach (var itemFromSet1 in itemSet1)
{
  //O(1)   
  if (!itemSet2.ContainsKey(itemFromSet1.IdentityValue))
  { 
     //do stuff to create item in the persistent store
  }
  else
  {
    //do stuff to update item in the persistent store
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find a performance improvement with the use of a HashSet.

```
        List<Foo> itemSet1 = GenerateLargeItemSet(); //makes a large list, > 5000 items for example
        HashSet<Foo> itemSet2 = new HashSet<Foo>(GenerateLargeItemSet());

        foreach (var itemFromSet1 in itemSet1)
        {
            //does a corresponding item exist in itemSet2?
            if (itemSet2.Contains(itemFromSet1))
            {
                //do stuff to update item in the persistent store
            }

            //do stuff to create item in the persistent store
        }
```

Comment: I am not comparing the objects. I am comparing a property value on the objects to determine if they are equal.

Comment: @StingyJack That just means you need to provide a comparer to the set, if the object hasn't defined equality based on that property.

Comment: @StingyJack Alternatively, you can just store the result of the selector in the set and perform the selector on the object before searching the set.  Either way, trivial adaptation.